# How to retrieve list of Firebase authenticated users and download them in JSON format?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I am new to firebase, I wanted to retrieve list of my authenticated users in JSON Format 
    I have searched for the solution but couldn't have found, some say it isn't possible !!!
    Please, someone, tell me whether it is possible or any other alternative ways to 
    get my users username/displayName/emailId or any other description based on their SignUp method.
I found a way to do it but I got an error , using Nodejs with this command :

```
**firebase auth:export users.json --format=json --project projectname**
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the user you have signed in as doesn't have access to the project you're trying to retrieve the user list from. Try `firebase logout` and `firebase login` with the correct user.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Could you elaborate more , is it really possible to retrieve list of my authenticated users from Firebase into a json format file ?

Comment: The [`auth:export` command](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authexport) exports the Firebase Authentication users and can store them as JSON. Since you're having trouble running the command, I'm trying to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried the command many times but the access is denied , I logged in and logged out many times but face the same error.
Have you ever succeeded in such case ?

Comment: I just ran `firebase auth:export users.json --project babel-fire`. It exported the users of that project without any problems

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather indirect answer, but, when they sign up, you could add the info you need about the user to the Firebase live database. Then, when you retrieve that information from the database, it's in JSON. I guess this probably isn't the answer you were looking for, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have `firebase-cli` installed on your computer. If so, just use `firebase auth:export <name.format> --project <project-id>` from the command line.

You can read more about the exported file from their tutorials [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth).